# DFS implementation in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, depth-first-search

I have written below code. However I am not sure if I have inserted my tree correctly. The code compiles sucessfully but I don't get the DFS traversed array in the output. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong ?

The input tree is below but please let me know if I have made the correct calls in the main function ? As my output is coming - [a b c d e f g h i j k]. whereas the correct output should be [a b e f i j c d g k h].

```
    A
  / \ \
 B   C D
/ \   / \
E  F  G  H
 / \  \
I  J  K
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
      string name;
      vector <Node *> children;

      Node(string name)
      {
          this->name = name;
      }

      //O(v+e) time | O(v) space
      vector <string> depthFirstSearch(vector<string> *array)
      {
          array->push_back(this->name);
          for(size_t i = 0; i < this->children.size(); i++)
               children[i]->depthFirstSearch(array);


          return *array;
      }

      Node *addChild(string name)
      {
          Node *child = new Node(name);
          children.push_back(child);
          return this;
      }
};

int main()
{
    Node n1("a");



    n1.addChild("b");
    n1.addChild("c");
    n1.addChild("d");
    n1.children[0]->addChild("e");
    n1.children[0]->addChild("f");
    n1.children[0]->children[1]->addChild("i");
    n1.children[0]->children[1]->addChild("j");
    n1.children[2]->addChild("g");
    n1.children[2]->addChild("h");
    n1.children[2]->children[0]->addChild("k");
    vector <string> array;
    n1.depthFirstSearch(&array);




    for (size_t i = 0; i< array.size(); i++)
        cout<<array[i]<<' ';



}
```

Note - Thanks for the explanation , but I made some edits in the way I constructed the tree in the main function and continued using return this statement and it worked.

Comment: Your tree representatin is confusing. Does A have three childs? B, C and D?

Comment: @Scheff Good point. I admit to a little binary-tree-focused narrow-mindedness. ;-) Still, I got one "agree" on that comment. So maybe being explicit about it would be helpful. And the tree representation is slightly odd elsewhere, too.

Comment: `addChild` return `this`. Should it not return `child` ?

Comment: @Damien Actually a simple bug but hard to catch as long as you focus on `depthFirstSearch()`... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually simple but not where it might be expected.

The `Node::addChild()` returns `this`:

```
      Node *addChild(string name)
      {
          Node *child = new Node(name);
          children.push_back(child);
          return this; // <-- OUCH!
      }
```

So, when used in `main()`:

```
    Node n1("a");
    Node *n2 = n1.addChild("b"); // => n2 = &n1;
    n1.addChild("c");
    Node *n4 = n1.addChild("d"); // => n4 = &n1;
    n2->addChild("e");
    Node *n3 = n2->addChild("f"); // => n3 = n2 = &n1;
    n3->addChild("i");
    n3->addChild("j");
    Node *n5 = n4->addChild("g"); // => n5 = n4 = &n1;
    n4->addChild("h");
    n5->addChild("k");
```

So, the tree actually does not get the expected shape but rather something like:

```
   A________________
  / \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \
 B   C D E F G H I J K
```

for what the current output of OP is fully correct.

The fix is simple:

```
      Node *addChild(string name)
      {
          Node *child = new Node(name);
          children.push_back(child);
          return child;
      }
```

Output:

```
a b e f i j c d g k h
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7550691721a396b6)

---

OP insisted in that `Node::addChild()` has to `return this;` and asked for another way to circumvent the issue. I tried to convince OP that `return child;` would make more sense than `return this;`.

Actually, I intuitively expected that `Node::addChild()` would return the the created child which costed me some extra debugging to find the actual bug. :-)

Concerning

> the way I have constructed my tree in the main function - is it the right way or there can be more efficient way of doing that

I personally find the code in `main()` not that bad as it is.

However, there are often more than one way to Rome.

So, here is just another idea:

A second constructor to construct child nodes explicitly:

```
      Node(Node &parent, string name): Node(name)
      {
        parent.children.push_back(this);
      }
```

which allows to write the tree init. in `main()` like this:

```
    Node nA("a");
    Node nB(nA, "b");
    Node nC(nA, "c");
    Node nD(nA, "d");
    Node nE(nB, "e");
    Node nF(nB, "f");
    Node nI(nF, "i");
    Node nJ(nF, "j");
    Node nG(nD, "g");
    Node nH(nD, "h");
    Node nK(nG, "k");
```

(`Node::addChild()` is even not used/needed in this case.)

Output:

```
a b e f i j c d g k h
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f48da3a9f56dcdea)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It works fine now. But my confusion is - the way I have constructed my tree in the main function - is it the right way or there can be more efficient way of doing that . What I want is do not change "return this to return child" and I want to know is there a way we write in main function our tree construction that the code will work with "return this " also .

Comment: Forgot to tag you.

Comment: @islia If you don't `return child;` then how do you get the pointer to the node created inside `Node::addChild()`? On the other hand, why `return this;`? `this` is something you definitely know beforehand. (Otherwise you couldn't call `addChild()` for a certain node because `return this;` just returns the node for which `addChild()` was called.)

Comment: @islia There are cases where `return this;` (or `return *this;`) makes sense to allow chaining of operators or member function calls. (The idiomatic overloading of `operator=()` is well-known example.) I wouldn't consider your `Node::addChild()` as such a case.

Comment: I edited my code and changed the way i constructed the tree and also included return this. The code worked correctly.